# "o76.getSource EXTERNAL table not supported" Error with AWS Glue custom connector with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, aws-glue

I was following this step by step to [connect data from BQ to AWS Glue and store in S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrating-data-from-google-bigquery-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-glue-custom-connectors/) , everything works ok until i tried to run the job, where the job keeps failing with:

```
An error occurred while calling o76.getSource. The type of table {datasetName}.{table_name} is currently not supported: EXTERNAL
```

I can't seem to find any similar error online, also can't find further helpful info from the log, it seems that it's stuck at the issue with the BQ table, I was following exactly as what the author did [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrating-data-from-google-bigquery-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-glue-custom-connectors/#:%7E:text=option.-,Add%20following%20Key%2FValue,data.covid19_open_data,-Choose) in the blog with the key-value pair to indicate project ID and dataset/table (image refers to blog's author table name).

[image]

Does anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have used your GCP big query project in a) and you've used full `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data`. Did you check with another public data?

Comment: yes i tried with other public data but not with BQ public data. However one weird thing is that it worked now, still unsure what went wrong as I didn't really change much configurations

Comment: Maybe it needed some time to replicate everywhere. Well another public BQ could be ``bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data_eu.covid19_open_data`` So in short it was solved and root cause is still unknown?